# C# - TcpClient first read after ConnectionAborted socket error is very slow

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient

I'm currently writing code that interacts with a device with TCP/IP.  After 15 seconds of inactivity the device is written to send a FIN packet to disconnect.  I'm using Polly for retries where I make sure to dispose of the TcpClient object, instantiate a new instance, and then reconnect to the IP/port before retrying the IO operation again.

In this case I'm trying to read a response from the connected socket.  The retry policy works and I get the response but I have noticed that when it does have to retry (due to a `ConnectionAborted` socket exception) it takes approximately 15 seconds before reading bytes into the buffer completes.  I don't do a lot of network programming so I'm relatively ignorant in this area and I have no idea why it takes so long.

```cs
// Retry policy and the TcpClient are private member variables in this case
_readRetryPolicy = Policy.Handle<IOException>()
    .RetryAsync(3, onRetryAsync: async (_, _) =>
    {
        Disconnect();
        await ConnectAsync(_ip!, _port).ConfigureAwait(false);
    });

public async Task<byte[]> ReadResponseAsync()
{
    if (_tcpClient is not TcpClient { Connected: true })
    {
        Disconnect();
        await ConnectAsync(_ip!, _port).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Possible StackOverflowException but I'm just hacking at this problem right now
        return await ReadResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    var buffer = new byte[32];
    var responseBytesStream = Enumerable.Empty<byte>();
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        numBytesRead = await _readRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => _tcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer).AsTask()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        responseBytesStream = responseBytesStream.Concat(buffer);
    }
    while (_tcpClient.GetStream().DataAvailable);

    return responseBytesStream.ToArray();
}

public void Disconnect()
{
    if (_tcpClient is TcpClient c) c.Dispose();
    _tcpClient = null;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set it to use KeepAlive `_tcpClient.Client.SetSocketOption( SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);`

Comment: I did have that at one point, except using IOControl to set the interval, but unfortunately the device ignores Keep-Alive packets.  I'm trying to protect the consumer of the API from instances of LAN cable getting reseated or they don't interact with the device within the 15 second limit.  They should expect some kind of delay because I have to disconnect and reconnect again but it is surprising that the first read after reconnect takes as long as it does.  If you try to interact between a FIN packet and the next keep-alive it fails.  After the Keep-Alive packet it is fine.

Comment: I doubt you can retry just the read. You'd probably need to send first and then read. Each socket connection is independent.

Comment: @StephenCleary
Thank you!  That was the problem.  I'm assuming what was happening was the second attempt to read from the stream just sat and timed out because there was nothing there.  If you can put this in an answer I'll get it accepted and up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each socket connection is an independent stream of communication (technically, two streams, one going each way). So if you have an application that sent a command and then the connection was dropped, the application can reconnect but it probably needs to re-send that command. Retrying just the read is insufficient.

For reliability reasons, your application should always retry connections (re-sending commands as necessary until they are ACKed). But it's also not a bad idea to add in a heartbeat if your protocol supports it. This is an actual message (data) that is sent, not the TCP-level keepalive packets. This kind of message may be called keepalive, heartbeat, or noop. If you send that message every 8-10 seconds, you should avoid the disconnection most of the time.

In general, I discourage writing TCP/IP applications because there's a lot of pitfalls. It's a lot harder than it first appears. But if you don't have a choice in your protocol, then I do recommend watching my [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS) on developing a reliable C# application communicating over TCP/IP.

Comment: Instead of 14+ hours of video, do you have a blog for that, lol

Comment: @CodeCaster: I do have [a blog series](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that hits the most important points. The video develops a full proper modern solution, though, using asynchronous I/O, pipelines, and channels.